# Aligning two scrollable elements in the page

Tags: html, css, background, alignment

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07KsJ.png)

Ι'm trying to align two separate backgrounds in one html page, lets say the first part (in which it will be added a flexslider) and the remaining main-page. How can I exactly align these two backgrounds horizontally? Can you provide me an example? My code doesn't work well.

```
<style type="text/css">
#one {
    background-image: url("http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad8rgb.png");
    repeat: no repeat;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
}

#two {
    background-image: url("http://www.bit-101.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/background.png");
    repeat: no repeat;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6buswo1p/)**

Thanks in advance

Comment: @isherwood because adding a slideshow affecting the whole page. All I want is to "glue" two separate png images one below the other

Comment: @isherwood please see attachment http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=10zscrd&s=9#.VvV9evl97IV

Comment: i'm struggling to have my backgrounds aligned as shown in example.

Comment: @isherwood it is here https://jsfiddle.net/6buswo1p/ take a glance

Comment: Your description says horizontal, yet your example image shows vertical, and you have absolute positioning in your CSS for some reason. What should scroll? And you keep mentioning backgrounds, but really you're asking about HTML layout structure. Please edit your question to be very specific.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
> <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <style type="text/css">
   </style>
  </head> 
  <body>  

   <div style="background-image: url(img/3.png); 
 width:1250px; height:1366px;">    
   </div>

   <div style="background-image: url(img/two.png);  width:1250px;     
 height:1366px;">
   </div>


  </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: thanks but it needs additional adjustments..when i ran it in my browser does not scretching..  width:100%; height:auto; does not work as well:/